# Including Zend Framework using svn-externals, svn update fails half way

Tags: svn, zend-framework, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I would like to include Zend Framework into my repository using `svn:externals = -r24607 http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/tags/release-1.11.9/library/Zend/ Zend .`

I am using Tortoise SVN TortoiseSVN 1.6.16 on Windows 7.

When I try to run update, after a hundred files or so I get:

```
Error: REPORT of '/svn/framework/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body: An
Error: existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Error: (http://framework.zend.com)
```

I can run the update again, and it will add more files, however after a hundred files or so it will fail again.

What could be the problem? Do I have something misconfgured?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have misconfigured anything, but I think the defaults of Subversion (or TortoiseSVN) are not working well under your circumstances. If the checkout normally works, but halfway breaks, the normal reason is that the connection is not stable or too slow.

These are the workarounds:

- If you have configured a proxy section in your servers file (`TortoiseSVN > Settings > Network > Subversion server file > Edit`), the timeout set for Subversion may be too short. You can set it directly in the servers file. See [Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.confarea.html), and search there for timeout.
- Just restart the update up to the point that it finishes normally.

You may check if a normal checkout of the path http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/tags/release-1.11.9/library/Zend/  works well, but I don't think so.

Comment: And for tag URL additional revision specification is overkill, obviously

Comment: @LazyBadger This is to protect me from changes on the tag, since SVN does not disallow commits to the tag.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't have a proxy... Restarting the update does work, as I mentioned in the question, but updating Zend Framework 100 files at a time - is taking forever!

Comment: Another note, so far it doesn't seem to be the timeout, since the error says: "existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Comment: Gave up on Windows+TortoiseSVN and did the update on my server (the working copy is shared over Samba from my Linux development server). Update on Linux went much faster, and reached the end with no problems. Thanks for the help anyway!